# how can i run shell bash file in windows 10?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, nasm

i am trying to run this shell script in windows 10 but it is not running and showing errors. e.g. it is running well for command at line 6 for "asm bios/dosbios.asm bios/dosbios.sys" but at line number 7 for "asm boot/boot.asm  boot/boot.com", it is showing error:

```
nasm: error: no input file specified
```

even if all files are placed in there respective folders very well, and many errors further as well, i am new in shell scripting and does not know how to run this bunch of commands, will i have to process each line indivisually or all script file whole at once, How:

```
sh
set -e
asm() {
    nasm -o $2 $1
}
asm bios/dosbios.asm bios/dosbios.sys    <--------line 6
asm boot/boot.asm   boot/boot.com        <--------line 7
asm util/format.asm util/format.com
asm util/fdisk.asm  util/fdisk.com
asm util/reboot.asm util/reboot.com
asm util/mem.asm    util/mem.com
asm util/attrib.asm util/attrib.com

dd if=/dev/null of=dosbios.sys bs=512 seek=9

export MTOOLSRC=mtools.cfg

perl -e 'print chr(0xf6) x 2880 x 512' > disk/newdos.tmp

mformat -m 0xf8 -v DOS  a:
mcopy   bios/dosbios.sys a:io.sys
mcopy   msdos/msdos.sys a:
mcopy   msdos/*.com a:
mcopy   msdos/*.exe a:
mcopy   msdos1/*.com    a:

mcopy   util/*.com  a:
mcopy -a legal/*    a:
mcopy -a etc/*      a:

mattrib -a +s +h +r a:io.sys
mattrib -a +s +h +r a:msdos.sys

dd status=none if=boot/boot.com of=disk/newdos.tmp conv=notrunc
mv disk/newdos.tmp disk/newdos.img

pause
```

please help and guide
thanks!

Comment: Use a global path.

Comment: how can i convert "asm" file to "com" file.

Comment: don't know. Try typing a global paht.